# How to make Azure Native Client Application available to multiple tenants ionic?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, ionic2, cordova-plugins, azure-active-directory

I have a IONIC mobile application which using Azure Native App to authenticate Azure and Skype O365 Login.

For my tenant, app works just fine. Now I want my app to be work for multi tenant. How can I make my native app work for multiple tenant.

For Azure login I am using following cordova plugin.
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using the `common` for the authority instead of specific tenant there is no need additional operations to work for the multi-tenant since the native app register on Azure portal support multi-tenant by default.

You can refer the document below:

[How to sign in any Azure Active Directory (AD) user using the multi-tenant application pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#related-content)

Comment: Yes, I am using `common` for the authority. Here is my code for that.
`let authContext = new Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/common");`

But when I provided my app to microsoft guy for testing, He said that we did not adhere to the multitenant process description.  I dont know what else to look at.

Comment: @AqibMirza Could you please provide more details about the test setup and who at Microsoft is helping you with it?

Comment: @AqibMirza In-addition, did you get any error message when you login the app using the users from other tenants?

Comment: Nvm I got it done. Actually it was working when i checked by creating other tenant account. Don't know why Microsoft guy told me its not multi tenant. Thanks for the help :)